# jquery template not refreshing data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using jquery template to load data from WCF service. See code below

```
function loadTableDetails(id) {

    var input =
    {
        Id: id,
    };
    self.TableDetailList([]);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "../Service/Table/TableList",
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(allData) {
            var mappedData = $.map(allData, function(item) {

                return new TableDetailData(item);
            });

            self.TableDetailList(mappedData);
            $("#instructorTemplate").tmpl(self.TableDetailList())
                                    .appendTo("#instructorsList");


        }
    });

}
```

I am bind it to view like below

```
<table id="Table1" style="width: 100%;">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="tblResultsCol1" style="width: 20px" />
        <col class="tblResultsCol2" style="width: 80px" />

        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <script id="instructorTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

        <tr>


            <td style="padding: 0px; text-align: left">${Id}</td>
            <td style="padding: 0px;">${ListName}</td>

        </tr>
    </script>

    <tbody id="instructorsList">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am calling this function loadTableDetails on click event of button and pass Id from selected combobox item. It loads data correctly for first time. But when user selects another item in combox then it adds data from old result to the new result. In short it keeps on adding data from previous result. I also tried to empty observable array `self.TableDetailList([])` before I call service again but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the using of the `appendTo` in the line

```
$("#instructorTemplate").tmpl(self.TableDetailList())
                        .appendTo("#instructorsList");
```

you are always appending to existing table so the new entries always added to the end and the old ones never removed.

So you need to `empty()` your target first and then append the new values:

```
$("#instructorsList")
    .empty()
    .append($("#instructorTemplate").tmpl(self.TableDetailList());
```

Or you use the `html()` method to replace the whole content of the `#instructorsList`

```
$("#instructorsList")
    .html($("#instructorTemplate").tmpl(self.TableDetailList());
```

Comment: Bingo. Working perfectly. Thanks a ton. I am loading more than 30K records so is it ok to use jquery template? Its not taking much time to load data.

Comment: Now facing one issue. When i load those 30K records in my table. It takes lots of time to scroll the records. Should i ask new question for this?

Comment: If you are having a new issue like this performance problem the normal way is to ask a new question... but 30K a lot of records... and there can be lots underlying reasons why it is slow for you.

Comment: i have put up new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389512/scrolling-issue-in-my-table  Accepting answer for this question. Please do help me on other issues.