# scrolling issue in my table

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

This is in with continuation from my previous question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389094/jquery-template-not-refreshing-data)

Now my table is getting refreshed. But when there are more than 25K records, the scrolling takes lots of time. Its very hard to scroll on so many records.

What could be done here?

Comment: I read many post and it seems there is no solution for this. Many are suggesting to use paging. But do let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed up scrolling through large tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681431/how-to-speed-up-scrolling-through-large-tables)

Answer (score 2):

A table with 25K records is certainly a lot to handle for any browser. Please consider splitting it into several chunks and use some pagination plugins, for example: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: datatable is great for that, would be my choice too

Comment: @Fedor can i use this datatable with jquery template? or is just bind datatable with my observable array which returns 25K records

Comment: What do you mean by "with jquery template"?

Comment: @Fedor how to bind datatable using knockout observable array? Any examples

Comment: Check out kogrid. https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid.  examples got moved to http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/examples. Like others have suggested, server side paging is the way  to go for that much data